# How do I code a keyboard press to run a function in Microsoft Visual C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, key-bindings

I want to move a button using a function which will be activated through a keyboard button, but I can't seem to make it accept my input. If I try to run the function through a button press, it works fine, so I know the function is not to blame. What am I doing wrong that it's not accepting my keyboard input?

```
private void MoveLeft()
{
    _y = btnBot.Location.Y;
    _x = btnBot.Location.X;
btnBot.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(_x - 10,_y);
}    

void MoveLeft_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        MoveLeft();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your program running and in the foreground when the A key is pressed?

Comment: Have you verified that the event handler is being wired up correctly?

Comment: The keyDown will only be raised by the control that has the focus. That means if a button control on your form currently has the focus, none of the key events for your form will ever get raised.

Comment: You can set the Form.KeyPreview to true and make the handler at the form level instead.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that your form key handle event is triggered, even if another control has focus, make sure the KeyPreview property is set to true.

In your main form, add the following line, or set it during design time.

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

Comment: Is your KeyDown event handler tied to the main form? `MoveLeft()` looks like a method.

You can tie the event at design time, or add the following in your main form's constructor after `InitalizeComponent()`

`this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.MoveLeft_KeyDown);`